Updating object attribute from database in Django
Let's say I have a model representing a task:
class Task(models.Model):
    on_status = models.BooleanField()

    def run(self):
        if self.on_status:
            # do stuff

I run this task with Celery Beat and I have a dashboard running on Gunicorn both using the same database.
app = Celery("app")

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "run_task": {
        "task": "run_tasks",
        "schedule": 5.0,
        "options": {
            "expires": 6.0,
        },
    },
}


tasks = Task.objects.all()


@app.task
def run_tasks():
    for task in tasks:
        task.run()

I can change on_status from my dashboard, but then I need to  update self.on_status of the instance inside Celery Beat process. Is there a command to update attribute value from database or is there a different approach?

@ViaTech How does that help my problem?

Well your posted code is not the standard format of any PeriodicTask or CronTask I've seen defined in django-celery-beats...which looks like you aren't using the right package. I have removed the note though, if you are using django-celery-beat, I did not see that easily defined in the code as I have seen it used the last 6 years in my systems, which is why I suggested it. For example, in django-celery-beat you simply define shared tasks as a decorator and beats links the DB to the task and you don't have your own model. Glad you figured out your issue though!

Regardless of how you are using celery-beat, the core question seems to be how you can refresh a django model object. That is done with refresh_from_db: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database
